# Why are the leaves on my kiwiberry curling?

Tags: kiwifruit

I've had this kiwiberry for about 1 year now, it's been potted the whole time.

[image]

I used regular compost potting mix, along with a handful of [Osmocote fertiliser](http://www.bunnings.com.au/osmocote-500g-fruit-citrus-trees-shrubs-fertiliser_p2961295) when I potted it. I water in the mornings and evenings, about 1-2 litres each time.

I also apply some [Seasol](http://www.bunnings.com.au/seasol-2l-hose-on-complete-garden-health-treatment-twin-pack_p3018004) once every month

I'm in Melbourne, Australia, could the dryness and heat be causing this? Am I not fertilising enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This looks like heat and sun based curling. Plants protect themselves by curling their leaves so part of the leaf is shaded. If you can get it out of the direct noon sun, but still give it morning and afternoon sun, I think the plant will be happier.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean Actinidia arguta (which is what this looks like), the pot is a problem. These plants are large, vigorous climbers, even the dwarf variety 'Issai' will reach 12 feet, so yours, being contained in a pot for a year, won't be doing too well. Your plant looks as if it's not getting enough water, and has a generally restricted appearance, which probably reflects the restriction at the root. If a plant has too much root in a container, it's pretty difficult for it to get enough water because the root to soil ratio is incorrect. Can you not find a spot in the ground for it, where you can train it up a vertical support?